# Display random usernames from mysql database in php echo

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wanna ask how to display database usernames from mysql in php echo

```
    $send = $database->query('SELECT * FROM `usernames` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($send)) {
    echo ''.$show['usernames'];
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem with your code?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: The problem is this <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the php error:

```
$ts = $database->query('SELECT * FROM `usernames` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
while ($show = $ts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo ''.$show['usernames'];
}
```

For sake of completeness you expect only 1 row of results so while-loop could be redundant:

```
$ts = $database->query('SELECT * FROM `usernames` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$show = $ts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $show['usernames'];
```

Comment: Worked! Thanx you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'usernames` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
foreach ($record as $d){
echo $d;
    }
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usernames` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
$send = mysql_query($query);
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($send)) {
    echo ''.$show['usernames'];
}
```

Comment: It working now, I'm using pdo